# Why is $E[u] = \int_{\Omega}\frac12 |\nabla u|^2 + \frac14u^4 dx$ a convex functional?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

In our PDE class, we examined the functional

$$E[u] = \int_{\Omega}\frac12 |\nabla u|^2 + \frac14u^4 dx.$$

My professor claimed that this functional was convex. When I take the derivative of the functional at $u$ in the $(v-u)$ direction, I get

$$\partial_{tt} E[u+t(v-u)] = \int_{\Omega}|\nabla (v-u)|^2 dx + \int_{\Omega}u^2(v-u)^2\\+2t\int_{\Omega}3u(v-u)^3 dx + 3t^2 \int_{\Omega}(v-u)^4.$$

If it is convex, I should be able to show that this positive for all $t>0$. But the third term is giving me trouble. What am I missing?

Comment: What does it mean for a functional to be convex?

Comment: $E[(1-t)u + tv] \leq (1-t)E[u] + tE[v]$ for $t\in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I'd write it:

$$\partial_{t} E[u+t(v-u)] = \int_{\Omega}\left[(\nabla u + t\nabla (v-u))\cdot \nabla (v-u) + (u+t(v-u))^3(v-u) \right] dx.$$

$$\partial_{tt} E[u+t(v-u)] = \int_{\Omega} \left[ |\nabla (v-u)|^2 + 3(u+t(v-u))^2(v-u)^2 \right] dx.$$

In your equation, there should be a 3 in front of the second term, which allows you to complete the square.

Comment: Thank you! That was really bothering me